# Spring Boot - Multiple login pages with dynamically added paths - 405 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've got a problem with my Spring Boot application in which im trying to implement dynamically configured multiple login pages.

In the database are stored prefixes for pages and I'm trying to get multiple paths for separate login pages.

I'm trying to do it in the following SecurityConfig class 
(*global.getPath() returns a plain prefix String*):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true )
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private GlobalSettingsService globalSettingsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<GlobalSettings> globals = globalSettingsService.findAll();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/js/**", "/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/fonts/**", "/img/**").permitAll();
        for (GlobalSettings global : globals) {
            http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/"+global.getPath()+"/**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/"+global.getPath()+"/admin/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/"+global.getPath()+"/login")
                    .loginPage("/"+global.getPath()+"/login").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/"+global.getPath()+"/admin")
                .failureUrl("/"+global.getPath()+"/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"+global.getPath()+"/login?logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/"+global.getPath()+"/login?logout")
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Login forms views are configured in another class (WebConfig) which extends WebMvcConfigureAdapter:

```
for (GlobalSettings global : globals) {
            registry.addViewController("/"+global.getPath()+"/login").setViewName(global.getPath()+"-/login-form");
        }
```

I've got 3 prefixes to configure and the last one configured in the loop is working correctly (propably with the highest order?) - I can log in and out without any troubles.

So the configuration works only for the last prefix which is called in the loop. Other prefixes are rendering proper login forms but returning 405 code after login attempt with following message:

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

So I made custom POST method definition in one of my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path}/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@PathVariable("path") String path, @RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
        return new ModelAndView(path+"-front/login-form", "error", error);
}
```

But unfortunately it's not being recognized, still getting 'Method not supported' message, while the login request path is correct.

Besides, the paths are mapping correctly during application initialization so I don't know where the problem is.
I tried many ways such as adding hidden _csrf field to the login form and still getting nothing.

Is it possible to do it avoiding prefixes hardcoding? 
Is it related with @Order annotation or something like this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your mapping in the loop should start with `http.antMatchers("/" + global.getPath() + "/**").authorizeRequests().` and then the remainder of your configuration. This to enable matching of configuration to different sections. Next to that what you should do is you should have (probably) multiple `WebSecurityConfigurer`'s. 1 for each `GlobalSettings` to make it work. You are now configuring a single `HttpSecurity` element so only 1 login/logout will remain in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact I thought it could be done dynamically but I did it in the way you suggested (separate WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters) and it works.
I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by rebuilding SecurityConfig class making separate WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters for each of my prefix:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true )
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private GlobalSettingsService globalSettingsService;

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class FirstPrefixWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/app1/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app1/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app1/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app1/admin/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/app1/login")
                .loginPage("/app1/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app1/admin")
                .failureUrl("/app1/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app1/login?logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/app1/login?logout")
                .permitAll();

        }
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class SecondPrefixWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/app2/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app2/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app2/admin/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/app2/login")
                .loginPage("/app2/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app2/admin")
                .failureUrl("/app2/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app2/login?logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/app2/login?logout")
                .permitAll();


        }
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class ThirdPrefixWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/app3/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app3/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app3/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app3/admin/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/app3/login")
                .loginPage("/app3/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app3/admin")
                .failureUrl("/app3/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app3/login?logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/app3/login?logout")
                .permitAll();


        }
    }

}
```

It isn't a dynamic solution but it's alright for now.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this dynamically? I'm in need of the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had to do this with fixed configurations.